# In April 2019 our economy created 263000 new jobs, however, total employment went down from March to April by103000 jobs. Why this difference?

Tags: unemployment, united-states

https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/employed-persons

This link shows that total employment declined from March to April even though we added 263000 new jobs. Can someone explain why?

Comment: There is *job creation* and there is *job separation*. Job creation allows previously unemployed labor force to become employed, while job separation captures the fact that previously employed work force becoming unemployed.

Comment: @HerrK.: you should probably put that in the answer box.

Comment: @Fizz: Thanks. But honestly, I didn't read the linked report very carefully, so I'm not sure my comment would fully answer OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference comes from the source of the data. While both figures can be found in [the latest BLS report](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/pdf/empsit.pdf), the +263K comes from their *establishment survey*, which includes only non-farm jobs *as reported by employers*.

> Total nonfarm payroll employment increased by 263,000 in April, compared with an average monthly
>   gain of 213,000 over the prior 12 months. In April, notable jobs gains occurred in professional and
>   business services, construction, health care, and social assistance. (See table B-1.)

On the other hand, the -103K figure comes from the *household survey* and reflects a shrinkage on the workforce (due to a decrease in labor force participation).

> The household survey includes agricultural
>   workers, self-employed workers whose businesses
>   are unincorporated, unpaid family workers, and
>   private household workers among the employed.
>   These groups are excluded from the establishment
>   survey

Furthermore, in the latter (household) survey the number of the unemployed decreased even more by 387K. The difference between 387K and 103K is about 284K which is a good enough approximation for the 263K from the establishment survey given the different methodologies.

[image]